# Part of my object disappears In camera view

Tags: rendering, interface, camera

Hi newbie in blender here.

does anybody know how to solve the problem?

Outside view show the whole 3d model, but on camera and rendered it comes out like this:[image: bug on Camera view]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to increase your camera's clipping end value:

[image]

Comment: Tank you very much lukas :)